# How to write generic function with array input of floating point convertibles in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am taking my first foray into writing generic functions in Swift. What I am trying to do is write a function that takes an array input of any type as long as that type is convertible to a floating point number. I am wondering if I can leverage some of the Swift standard library protocols to do this. Here is a trivial example (I am searching for what to use as `ConvertibleToFloatingPointTypeProtocol`):

```
func toDoubleArray<T: ConvertibleToFloatingPointTypeProtocol>(array: [T]) -> [Double] {
    var doubleArray = [Double]()
    for arrayItem in array {
        doubleArray.append(Double(arrayItem))
    }
    return doubleArray
}
```

The compiler error I get from this when I try `FloatingPointType`, etc. is: "Cannot find an initializer for type 'Double' that accepts an argument list of type '(T)'"

Now I know another option is to create my own protocol and then extend the types that I am interested in to adopt it, but this just feels like something that exists right under my nose.

Comment: I don't think anything like this exists in stdlib, but you could create your own protocol.

Comment: Thanks @jtbandes, I know I can go that route, I was just sure this had to already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try `FloatLiteralConvertible`:

```
import Darwin

// Swift 2.0
func toDoubleArray<T : FloatLiteralConvertible>(arr : [T]) -> [Double] {
    return arr.flatMap { $0 as? Double }
}

// Swift 1.2
func toDoubleArray<T : FloatLiteralConvertible>(arr : [T]) -> [Double] {
    var result = [Double]()

    for a in arr {
        if let d = a as? Double {
            result.append(d)
        }
    }

    return result
}

let a = toDoubleArray([1, 2, 3])
let b = toDoubleArray([M_PI, 2 as Int, 3.3])
let c = toDoubleArray(["a", "b", "c"])  // Error, cannot convert [String] to [Double]
let d = toDoubleArray([1, 2, 3, "a"])   // Error, cannot convert [NSObject] to [Double]
```

Comment: Trying this out in the playground I get "Cannot invoke 'flatMap' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'"

Comment: `(1 as Int) as? Double` returns nil for me.

Comment: @ScottH should have mentioned that I tested it in Swift 2.0. For 1.2, `flatMap` doesn't recognize the input and return type. Had to replace it with an old school loop.

Comment: @ZoffDino thanks. At first blush that looks good, but I don't think it gets me to where I want to be. I'd like to be able to define a new object that conforms to this protocol as well and can also be used in an array with `Int`s and `Double`s. For example:

`class MyClass: FloatLiteralConvertible {
    var myValue: Double
    required init(floatLiteral value: FloatLiteralType) {
        myValue = value
    }
}

let x: MyClass = 2.0

let badArray = [x, 10, 3.0]
let badResult = toDoubleArray(badArray) // NSArray is not convertible to Double`
**Sorry, don't know how to format code in a comment.**